# Aligned equations with multiple tags per line

Tags: equations, numbering, align

I would like to typeset something like this:

[image]

except that instead of having just one tag per line, I want one tag per equation (A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3), with each tag appearing to the right of its equation. The amsmath `align*` environment doesn't let me use `\tag` more than once per line.

I tried using `multicols`, but it was very fiddly and I couldn't get the alignment right, so I'm hoping there's a way similar to using `align`.

Here's a mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
 x &= x + 1     &    z &= \frac{y}{0}    &    \frac{d}{de} e^x &= xe^{x-1}  \tag{A1} \\[1em]
 \text{eggs} &= \text{bacon}   &  {,} &= {;}   &    7 &= 32  \tag{B1} \\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like to referencing each equation in the system of equation, than see the following solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
\begin{align}
 x & = x + 1                    \label{A1}\tag{A1}    \\
 \text{eggs} &= \text{bacon}    \label{B1}\tag{B1}
 \end{align}
\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
    \begin{align}
    z   & = \frac{y}{0} \label{A2}\tag{A2}    \\
    {,} & = {;}         \label{B2}\tag{B2}
    \end{align}
    \end{minipage}\begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
        \begin{align}
        \frac{d}{de} e^x & = xe^{x-1}   \label{A3}\tag{A3}    \\
                    7    & = 32         \label{B3}\tag{B3}
        \end{align}
    \end{minipage}
\end{center}
See equations \eqref{A1}, \eqref{B2} and \eqref{A3} \dots
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text area border)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a self-answer - I'm not sure why I didn't think of it, but you can just fake the tags using `align*`. The right-hand tags don't line up with the tags from normal equations, but I find that not so bad.

Of course, I'm very open to better suggestions, especially since someone else want to do the same thing but using the automatic equation numbers instead of manual tags.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
 x &= x + 1                    &\text{(A1)}&&\qquad
 z &= \frac{y}{0}              &\text{(A2)}&&\qquad
 \frac{d}{de} e^x &= xe^{x-1}  &\text{(A3)}
 \\[1em]
 %
 \text{eggs} &= \text{bacon}   &\text{(B1)}&&\qquad
 {,} &= {;}                    &\text{(B2)}&&\qquad
 7 &= 32                       &\text{(B3)}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your equations is not possible to cross-referenced :-(

Comment: @Zarko sure, that's why I accepted your answer instead of mine! (We posted them at the same time I think.)